# 18-55 VRII or 35mm 1.8 for Nikon D3300

Tags: lens, focal-length, prime, kit-lens, nikon-d3300

I own a 18-55 kit lens for my Nikon D3300. i plan to sell it and buy a 35mm 1.8 prime lens. will it worth. i think there is no much difference in focal range of the both

Comment: [if I have a 18-55mm lens is there a point in buying a 35mm prime?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15573/if-i-have-a-18-55mm-lens-is-there-a-point-in-buying-a-35mm-prime-lens)

Comment: As someone who's been there and done that and asked the same question, definitely keep the 18-55 if for no other reason than to use the 18mm end of it. Wide angle can be nice in very tight quarters or if you want to get more of a subject's surroundings. Plus it's a hell of a lot cheaper than buying a dedicated wide-angle lens for the few occasions where you'd want to use it. (Edit: but buy the 35mm too. They retail for like $120, not a bank-breaker and will be a lifesaver in low-light conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference between these two lenses is the fact that one is a zoom lens, and the other is a prime lens. Prime lenses usually offer better optical performance, at the same focal lengths, than a zoom lens.

The aperture is denoted by the f-number, and the 35 has a **larger** aperture, denoted by it's **smaller** f-number, i.e., 1.8.

A larger aperture gives you the creamy bokeh that successfully isolates the subject from the background, and is also very aesthetic, like this. This was shot by [Brandon Woelfel on Instagram.](https://www.instagram.com/brandonwoelfel/?hl=en)
[image: Not exactly like this, but you get the idea.]

On a Nikon D3300, which has an APS-C sensor, you would get the equivalent of 52 mm, not 35, which is perfect for daily use, street photography, and the casual video shoot too. This is because APS-C sensors in Nikon cameras have a crop factor of 1.5x.

I have the 35mm too, and it is fantastic. 
You should definitely go for it.

Comment: do you think i dont need 18 55 after that. So can i sell it

Comment: @laughs keep the 18-55, as it is useful when you have to take some wide shots. wait a bit and buy the 35 then. If it is urgent, then by all means, sell it.

Comment: @laughs You might want to search eBay to see what a used 18-55 VR sells for. You may not get that much for it since new it isn't that expensive. I would keep it; you might find the extra range useful at times.

Comment: Confirm, I used the 35 with my D90, it is really excellent. Not just the bookeh and aperture but the general image quality and sharpness is great.