# What results can I expect from monochrome digital camera modification?

Tags: monochrome

I know of the Leica Monochrome (black and white) camera, but it is too expensive for me (my budget is about $1,200). Is it there a service that will modify the sensor of a camera to make it truly a B&W camera? Has anyone had experience with that conversion?

Comment: It would be nessesary to remove a very close filter layer form directly above the photodiodes...which is probably nearly impossible. (Especially for this budget, but if somebody know better, let me know) 
If you don't want exactly the better sharpness, then convert the color photo into a monochrome digital. and setup the displayed saturation on the ca display to 0.

Comment: Many cameras allow you to apply a monochrome picture style in camera, or if shooting RAW as a post process? Why on earth would you fork out extra money just to have a dedicated monochrome cam?

Comment: @CrazyDino Because the Bayer filter and the algorithm to decode the reading into a colour image affects image quality. Colour is interpolated from that output.
Fuji's XTrans layout has a different pixel layout to avoid problems like moiré without using more filters that softens the image, IIRC. 
So there's some value that if all you cared is black and white, ditching the filter can yield better results.

Answer (score 5):

A monochrome conversion is not feasible (it would require removing of the [Bayer filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) and a major rewrite of firmware).

But it is not really necessary, as the monochrome conversion can be easily applied in post processing, and any increase of sharpness is - in context of modern sensors, which are *not* resolution constrained - Leica marketing hot air.

More to the point: a major aspect of monochrome photography work is tweaking intensity of different colors / wavelengths. In the olden days of film this was done with color filters (yellow, orange, red and what not... ).

In digital workflow it is done not in camera but in post process, but you require a color raw file to start with. Your flexibility increases, as you are not limited by the range of filters available, and you can make multiple final images out of original raw file just by changing settings - it is actually quite educating to learn about filter effect.

Comment: What (theoretically) is not made-up marketing is the increased sensitivity of up to 2/3 stops. Still: It's not feasible.

Comment: What is also not made-up marketing is the sharpness gained by not having to de-bayerize the recorded image data.

Comment: I do not dispute that a B&W camera would have (slightly :) improved sensitivity and sharpness compared to full color one. My argument is that sensitivity and image sharpness are not major constraints for modern sensors, and thus the improvements you describe would be negligible in most use cases.
IMHO the potential for manipulation of full color image in post process is much more important from creative point of view.

Comment: @JindraLacko That's a judgement that is primarily opinion based that depends on which is more important to a particular user: increased sensitivity and resolution *or* increased flexibility in post processing. For some, the former is more important. For others, the latter is more important.

Comment: The other thing to realize here is that using a de-Bayerized sensor with an actual color filter over the lens has the same effect on sensitivity as using a Bayer mask directly over the sensor. The stronger the color filter, the more the light reaching the sensor is reduced. That's not much different from monochrome images made using Bayer masked sensors, where the the further the WB (on all axes, not just CT) is shifted away from a 'neutral' amplification the lower the effective sensitivity of the sensor is.

Comment: @MichaelClark I sort of agree - yes, I have a strong opinion on the matter. But on the other hand if there was a market for pure monochrome digital there would be more of them on the market. The Fuji / Canon / Nikon guys are anything but stupid, and if there was market they would sniff it out. As far as I know Leica M Monochrom and Phase One IQ3 100MP Achromatic are the only two monochrome digital cameras I know. The market seems to have settled on what it wants...

Comment: It's hard to say that for sure since the market has never offered a relatively low cost camera with a high resolution monochrome sensor. There might be a lot more takers than they think.

Comment: For years everyone said Michael Johnston's *Decisive Digital Camera* would never be made because no one would buy such a thing. Then Sigma released the DP1 and it was a success. https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/87279/15871

Answer (score 0):

maxmax.com can replace some Fujifilm digital cameras' sensor with monochrome one.

There are rumors that Fujifilm considered monochrome X100*, but got enough positive feedback from opinion polls.

(consider also switching to film camera with B&W film, as I did :) ).